# Is it possible to preview Angular template?

Tags: html, css, angular

Is there a way to preview Angular template (i.e. see how HTML would be rendered) without starting the whole application?
I'm working on CSS styling and it would be easier to be able to see changes immediately.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to preview Angular template (i.e. see how HTML would be
>   rendered) without starting the whole application?

You can't. **There's only one way which is starting your Angular application**. One reason is that in the Angular application, your CSS doesn't directly affect the HTML like in a normal standalone webpage.